# Como eu posso utilizar python com c++?

Tags: python, c++

Eu descobri que posso utilizar duas linguagens de programação no mesmo programa, porém não sei exatamente fazer isto... Eu queria apenas uma ideia num exemplo bem simples para fazer funcionar o código abaixo e eu aprender.

Eu tenho um programa em python que possui um input do tipo inteiro (int), o usuário digita qualquer valor nele abaixo de 300:

```
num = int(input("Digite o número: "))
```

Após isto eu queria de alguma forma passar o valor de `num` para um código em C++ que apenas executa um laço `for` com o valor dado em `num`:

```
//nota-se que o valor de 'a' seria o valor atribuído na variável 'num' no arquivo .py 
for(a=num; a<300; a++){
   cout << a << endl;
}
```

Eu tinha primeiramente pensado em colocar por exemplo um `#include`, mas não sei se fazer tal coisa resultaria algum erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem de definir se quer a) chamar código C++ a partir do Python e/ou b) chamar código Python a partir de C++.

No caso (a) você deve pesquisar sobre como estender o Python e desenvolver módulos Python em C/C++. O começo é a documentação da linguagem, até para entender os desafios envolvidos: https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html

Há outras opções que devem ser consideradas, por serem mais práticas: Boost.Python, Cython, SWIG, FFI, etc. A melhor ferramenta vai depender do seu caso particular.

No caso (b) o que você deseja é fazer um "embedding" da máquina Python dentro de um programa C/C++. Documentação básica: https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html

Python não é considerada a linguagem mais fácil de "embebedar"; Lua ganha o troféu neste ponto.